# Safari Server Sent Event (SSE) Infinte Loop

Tags: javascript, safari, eventsource

I am having issues with server-send events (SSE) in Safari 9 and Safari 10. The SSE connection opens, immediately closes and then reconnects in an infinite loop.

This is the client side code:

```
var events = new EventSource("/stream/events")
```

These are the http response headers:

```
> GET /stream/events HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/event-stream
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 19 Sep 2017 05:28:22 GMT
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-Accel-Buffering: no
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2017 05:28:22 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Some additional notes:

- I tested in Chrome and Firefox and cannot repeat
- I tested in Safari **without https** and cannot repeat
- I tested in Safari **with https** and can repeat
- The https certificates are auto-generated using Lets Encrypt
- The backend server is written in Go and uses http/2 by default

The fact that I can only repeat in Safari with https is interesting. I am therefore wondering if there are any known issues with SSE and https, or if there is anything else I might be misconfiguring or missing here.

**EDIT**

I have isolated the problem and found a correlation to the protocol. When the http2 protocol is enabled, I am able to reproduce this issue. When http2 is disabled on the server, I am no longer able to reproduce this problem.

I used the following server patch to verify:

```
--- before.go   2017-09-19 13:31:45.668891000 -0400
+++ after.go    2017-09-19 13:31:55.100891000 -0400
@@ -2,6 +2,6 @@
            Addr: ":443",
            TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
                GetCertificate: manager.GetCertificate,
-               NextProtos:     []string{"h2", "http/1.1"},
+               NextProtos:     []string{"http/1.1"},
            },
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the headers that Safari is sending? My guess is there a HEAD or OPTIONS request being sent, before the GET request, and that your back-end script is not handling it. (The http/2 angle is interesting.) (I am posting as a comment, rather than an answer, as this is quite a wild guess at the moment, but see ch.9 of my book, Data Push Apps with HTML5 SSE, where Safari was the browser that behaved differently.)

Comment: Thanks for the question. The server is configured to reply to all OPTIONS and HEAD requests, however, according to the server logs we are receiving neither. I disabled http2 and everything is working as expected with my application, so at least I have a temporary workaround. I tested in Safari 9 / 10 / 11 / webkit nightly, so at this point I think creating a webkit bug report might be the next step.

Comment: Is it possible to look at Safari to see what requests and headers it is sending? I.e. like the web developer screens you get (built-in now) with Chrome and Firefox. It will be interesting to see if Safari's view of events matches those of your server logs.

Comment: the network tab only shows a single GET entry for the request.

Answer (score 2):

I bet that the Safari javascript console is filled with:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: The operation couldnt be completed. Protocol error
```

and it is very probably a protocol error. The [section 8.1.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.2) of the http/2 says that

> An endpoint MUST NOT generate an HTTP/2 message containing connection-specific header fields; any message containing connection-specific header fields MUST be treated as malformed.

I cannot ensure that this is your problem, since I don't see the HTTP headers of your http/2 attempt, but many http/2 implementations made the choice of still sending `Connection: Keep-Alive` headers while several user agents, including Safari and curl, decided to be strict on the matter.

UPDATE

I should add that the faulty header, most probably the standard `Connection: keep-alive' one, can have been set by any server side component (typically the SSE server-side component of the application), not the container itself.  I bet that containers should filter it in http/2.

Comment: I had the same problem with SSL on safari mac (and ios), removing `Connection: keep-alive' solved the problem!